Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_wakeUpAfterNarrowphase') Ammojs object destroyed
How to prevent error log?
I do regulary removing body with physics.world.removeBody
Any Sugestion?
CODE
      collisionBox.addEventListener("collide", function(e) {
        // const contactNormal = new CANNON.Vec3();
        // var relativeVelocity = e.contact.getImpactVelocityAlongNormal();
        // console.log("playerCollisonBox collide with", e);
        preventDoubleJump = null;

        if(e.contact.bj._name == 'floor' || e.contact.bi._name == 'floor') {
          preventDoubleJump = null;
          return;
        }

        // ?maybe
        // App.scene.playerCollisonBox.physics.currentBody.mass = 10;

        if(e.contact.bi._name == 'damage') {
          console.log("Trigger damage!");
          //. 4x fix
          App.scene.player.energy.value -= (0.25 - (App.scene.player.items.armor ? App.scene.player.items.armor.preventDamage : 0));
          App.scene.player.updateEnergy(App.scene.player.energy.value);
        }

        if(e.contact.bj._name == 'item-armor' || e.contact.bi._name == 'item-armor') {
          console.log("Trigger armor:", e.contact);
          // Make some enery restore
          App.scene.player.energy.value += 0.25;
          App.scene.player.updateEnergy(App.scene.player.energy.value);
          App.scene.player.items.armor = {
            preventDamage: 0.15
          }

          if(App.scene['armor']) {
            App.scene['armor'].physics.enabled = false;
            App.scene['armor'].isHUD = true;
            App.scene.armor.position.setPosition(1.2, 1.1, -3);
            App.scene.armor.mesh.setScale(0.1)
            // Can be destroyed also 
            // App.scene['armor'].selfDestroy(1)
          }
          if(e.body._name == 'item-armor') {
            console.log("Trigger armor collect!");
            physics.world.removeBody(e.body);
          }
        }
      });


